# how to change svg text tag using javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

i was using raphaeljs , and i want to show html(not only text) in svg,

so i use this code :

```
var r = Raphael("holder", 200, 300);
var t = r.text(10, 10, "ssdwqdwq");
t.node.innerHTML='dddd'
```

but  i cant change  the svg's content , so i console it in firebug ,

```
console.log(t.node)
```

it show this :

```
<text x="10" y="13.5" text-anchor="middle" style="font: 10px "Arial";" font="10px "Arial"" stroke="none" fill="#000000">
```

so how to change the text using javscript on svg

thanks

Answer (score 89):

SVG nodes don't have a innerHTML property (they're not HTML).

Use textContent instead: `t.node.textContent='dddd'`

Comment: thanks, and how to change the text to html ??  ex: add <div>ddd</div>to t.node

Comment: You will probably need something like this (that second example is crazy!): http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg

Comment: This is also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118769/native-button-tag-inside-svg-canvas/4120189#4120189

Comment: Great answer, just what I was expecting!

Answer (score 15):

I was able to accomplish this by setting the textContent property of the `<text>` element. Makes it a lot easier if you know the ID of the element.

```
document.getElementById("id-of-text-el").textContent = "My Value";
```

Answer (score 8):

if the code for the svg text is like this:

```
<text id="id-of-the-text"> old value</text>
```

if you are using JQuery try this:

```
$("#id-of-the-text").text("new-value");
```

Comment: Or, without the burden of jQuery: `document.querySelector('text#id-of-the-text').textContent='new-value';`. This looks longer, but jQuery runs through about a hundred lines of code before doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Zecc's answer - it IS possible to use innerHtml to get content of SVG elements, for example( that i'm sure of) - of text element and  of a svg path

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33939643)

Answer (score 0):

Changing `ìnnerHTML` property for svg elements might have been a problem in 2010.

2023 it works flawlessly in all modern browsers:

```js
// OP's example 
var r = Raphael("holder", 200, 300);
var t = r.text(50, 50, "ssdwqdwq").attr({
  'font-size': 20,
  'font-family': 'Arial',
  'font-weight': 'bold',
  fill: '#000',
  width: 400
});
t.node.innerHTML='dddd';

/**
* add foreignObject 
* to enable HTML elements
* make sure to apply the correct namespaces 
* for <foreignObject> and inner <div>
*/
let nsSvg = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
let nsHtml = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
let foreignObject = document.createElementNS(nsSvg, 'foreignObject');
foreignObject.setAttribute('x', 20)
foreignObject.setAttribute('y', 50)
foreignObject.setAttribute('width', '100%')
foreignObject.setAttribute('height', 150)

let foreignObjectDiv = document.createElementNS(nsHtml, 'div');
foreignObjectDiv.innerHTML = `Foreign <em style="color:red">object</em> <strong>text</strong>`;
foreignObject.appendChild(foreignObjectDiv)

//append foreign object
r.canvas.appendChild(foreignObject)
```

```css
svg{
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}

text{
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.3.0/raphael.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder"></div>
```

#### Append HTML elements to SVG via [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)

It is crucial to use the correct namespaces when attaching the foreign object dynamically:

```
// foreignObject is a svg 
let foreignObject = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
// HTML element within foreign object
let foreignObjectDiv = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'div');
```

Keep in mind, `foreignObject`  will only work in applications with **HTML rendering support**.

A lot of **graphic/desktop applications might omit its content**.
You might also encounter issues trying to convert your svg to pdf in some libraries.

If you don't need **complex multiline text** layouts, you should better stick with SVG's native [`<text>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) and [`<tspan>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan) elements.

Answer (score 0):

My transpiler does not have the definition of `textContent` property
and I found an another answer in this [2879473](/q/45469908/2879473) question.

```
while (t.node.hasChild) {
    t.node.removeChild(t.firstChild);
}
var txt = document.createTextNode("ddd");
t.node.appendChild(txt);
```

you can get same results by `innerHTML`, but
DOM API may be a bit faster than property.
see [Maxim answer](/a/75900408/2879473)

(Sorry, I did not test `createTextNode` and `appendChild` spped)