# How to change innerHTML of an innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have such a JS code :

```
var parent = titles[i].parentElement;
console.log(parent.innerHTML);
```

That prints this on console :

```
<title style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">MyTitle</title>
```

How can I change `MyTitle` to something else? Thanks.

EDIT :

My whole code is this:

```
var titles = document.getElementsByTagName('title');
for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    if (titles[i].innerHTML == 'MyTitle') {
        console.log(titles[i].innerHTML);
        var parent = titles[i].parentElement;
        console.log(parent.innerHTML);
        titles[i].innerHTML == '1215546162';
        console.log(titles[i].innerHTML);
        $(parent).attr('fill', 'blue');
    }
}
```

Comment: `parent.innerText = "new"` or `$(parent).text("new")`

Comment: can you please share the html code?

Comment: document.title = "new title", but why you want to change by javascript?

Comment: Wouldn't you just say `titles[i].innerHTML = "something else"`? If the inner HTML of the parent is exactly one element then clearly `titles[i]` *is* the element you want to update.

Comment: Is this in an HTML document ? If so, how can you have a nodeList, array or whatever with more than a single `<title>` element ? To modify its innerHTML, just do `document.title = 'your Text';`. Ah thanks for the edit, so it's an svg document. You may want to clarify it in your question directly, and show us a bit of this svg markup.

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried what you said but it didn't work. I edited my answer.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Did you get an error, or did the wrong thing happen, or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn MyTitle stayed the same, it didn't change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change svg text tag using javascript innerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282108/how-to-change-svg-text-tag-using-javascript-innerhtml)

Comment: In your code you are doing         `titles[i].innerHTML == '1215546162';` it should be `titles[i].innerHTML = '1215546162';` (single `=`) or even `titles[i].textContent = '1215546162';` for old browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
titles[i].innerHTML="New Title";
```

Title is changing (look at console) at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ek6f9jq8/2/

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. My Suggestion works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ek6f9jq8/2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the the exact purpose of your code, but this can be helpful.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var title = head.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
title.innerHTML = "Foo";
```

Comment: or `document.title = 'Foo'`