# Formatting text from axis ticks in plotly using tickformat

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

Is possible to add format to the xaxis and yaxis ticks using tickformat?

The idea is cut long names of axis as:

```
axiswithaverylongname --> axisw...
```

In the plotly api reference there's and example to format dates
https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickformat

and also they refer to the d3 documentation 
https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md

from  the plotly reference:

```
tickformat (string) 
default: "" 
Sets the tick label formatting rule using d3 formatting mini-languages 
which are very similar to those in Python. For numbers, see: 
https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format 
And for dates see: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-
format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format We add one item to d3's 
date formatter: "%{n}f" for fractional seconds with n digits. For 
example, "2016-10-13 09:15:23.456" with tickformat "%H~%M~%S.%2f" 
would display "09~15~23.46"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of doing it directly via `tickformat` but a few lines of JavaScript code will fix it for you.

```
Plotly.d3.selectAll(".xtick text").each(function(d, i) {
  Plotly.d3.select(this).html(Plotly.d3.select(this).html().substr(0, 5));
});
```

Using d3's `seleectAll` wet get all `text` labels on the x-axis and update the text with the first 5 letters of the initial label.

You can either do it automatically or when the button is pressed in the example below.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: ["A", "B1", "axiswithaverylongname", "Wow, wait a second, that's way tooooo long"],
  y: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  type: "bar"
};

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myPlot')
Plotly.newPlot('myPlot', [trace1]);
document.getElementById("cleanButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
  Plotly.d3.selectAll(".xtick text").each(function(d, i) {
    if (Plotly.d3.select(this).html().length > 8) {
      Plotly.d3.select(this).html(Plotly.d3.select(this).html().substr(0, 5) + '...');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myPlot" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
<button id="cleanButton">Clean x-axis</button>
```

Comment: @alfaz jikani: I'll test it when I have access to a computer with IE11.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, I found working solution for IE11.
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285239/5492926
`Plotly.d3.selectAll(".xtick text, .ytick text").each(function (d, i) {
   // Using jquery
  // Use d.text instead of reading DOM by "Plotly.d3.select(this).html()"
  $(this).text(d.text.substr(0, 5));
 });`