# I would like to modify a <tspan> with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, tspan

I would like to modify the  with js but I can't do it. I have no error message.

js

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    function taux() {
      let rue = document.getElementById("input-rue").value;
      let tauxrue = document.getElementById("tr");
      tauxrue.innerText = rue;

<!-- language: lang-html -->
```

svg/html

```
    <text id="_33ème_édition_-_1019ème_gp" data-name="33ème édition - 1019ème gp" class="cls-5" transform="translate(122 162)"><tspan x="0" y="0" id="tr">33</tspan><tspan class="cls-6" y="0">ÈME</tspan><tspan y="0" xml:space="preserve"> ÉDITION - 1019</tspan><tspan class="cls-6" y="0">ÈME</tspan><tspan y="0" xml:space="preserve"> GP</tspan></text>
```

Comment: I cant see where your `let rue = document.getElementById("input-rue").value;` element is in your code.

Comment: First thing i notice is you didn't close your function brackets in the js

Comment: Hello, js is in js file but I do not understand your question.

Comment: input-rue it's just id of my input

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4282289/2610061

Comment: you can't add an SVG text element as a child of a tr element. You need <tr><svg><text><tspan></tspan></text></svg></tr>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `textContent`. Also I would defint the input and the tauxrue outside the function.

```js
let ir=document.getElementById("input-rue");
let tauxrue = document.getElementById("tr");

ir.addEventListener("input",taux)

function taux() {
      let rue = ir.value;
      tauxrue.textContent = rue;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-rue"/>

<svg viewBox="120 140 300 300"> 
<text id="_33ème_édition_-_1019ème_gp" data-name="33ème édition - 1019ème gp" class="cls-5" transform="translate(122 162)"><tspan x="0" y="0" id="tr">33</tspan>
  <tspan class="cls-6" y="0">ÈME</tspan>
  <tspan y="0" xml:space="preserve"> ÉDITION - 1019</tspan>
  <tspan class="cls-6" y="0">ÈME</tspan>
  <tspan y="0" xml:space="preserve"> GP</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry but taux is not defined `ir.addEventListener("input",taux)`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at taux (form.js:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (template-two.html:207)`