# Add HTML controls on Canvas for Raphael Library

Tags: javascript, raphael

How to add HTML controls [like textbox, combo box, button etc.] on canvas [we use paper] for Raphael Library?

I want to add on paper[canvas], not out side of paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use absolute positioning and z-index property [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Hwctx/).

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118769/native-button-tag-inside-svg-canvas)